# Storing class objects in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Is there there a way to store class objects in an `array` or `vector` in c++?

I have a class I am writing to do some basic fraction math.

```
Fraction fraction_1(a,b);
```

Is there a way to store each of those so that I can then add, subtract, multiply all the fractions later in my program?

ideally I would like to be able to just do say `List[2] + List[3]` (which would use my overloaded operator to do fraction addition)?

I am completely stuck trying to figure out a good way to do this as I do not have much experience with vectors in c++.

Comment: Yes, vectors hold class objects exactly the same as any other objects.  I'm having a hard time understanding your question.  What exactly are you having trouble with?  What have you tried?  Please edit these things into the question.

Comment: check out any basic tutorial covering C++ standard library containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can define a vector and add your elements to it:

```
std::vector<Fraction> fv;

fv.push_back(Fraction(a, b));
fv.push_back(Fraction(a, c));
fv.push_back(Fraction(d, c));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in exactly the same way as you would for any built in type.  i.e.

```
std::vector<int> foo;
std::vector<MyClass> bar;
std::vector<std::string> baz;

foo.push_back(1);
bar.push_back(my_class_object);
baz.push_back("hello");

foo[0] = 2;
bar[0] = my_other_object;
baz[0] = "world";
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to overload operators +, -, multiply and division for it to work the way you want it to.

You can store ANY type of data in a CONTAINER such as vector because they're templated.

```
vector <Fraction> array;
array.push_back(Fraction(10, 20));
array.push_back(Fraction(30, 40));

array2.push_back(array[0] + array[1]);
```

Comment: OP seems to already have overloaded operators, but not know how to use a vector.

Comment: Not *ANY* type.  There are various requirements, depending upon the member functions you use.